# Github... Background image doesn't display when I publish my site on github

Tags: github-for-windows

I'm a beginner in web Dev..  I have a website that displays properly on localhost but when I publish and try to render it on Github, the background image doesn't show up.. What can I do to remedy this

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a bit of code for us to look at?

My guess is that you have the background image referenced absolutely on the computer, and it needs to be a relative reference to render when hosted online, but I can't say for sure without having some code to look at.

A link to your github project would also help.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** It looks like you perhaps renamed your startup.css to style.css and forgot to edit the html header link from startup.css, to style.css

I.e. change

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="startup.css">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

**Previous suggestion (no longer likely):**
As you mention Windows, one possibility is that you have mixed up Capital and small letters somewhere in the filename or path.

Simple web-servers on Windows are often forgiving (as is Windows filesystem) of these mistakes, while internet is not-

Comment: Thank you very much